# Centos Apache version is not latest?

Tags: apache-http-server, centos-7

From apache website, it seems that latest version is 2.4.54.

I installed apache on my CentOS 7, and when I check the version, it shows that it installed the latest version, but the version number is `httpd-2.4.6-97.el7.centos.5.x86_64`:

```
# yum changelog httpd
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: changelog, fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.interhost.net.il
 * extras: centos.interhost.net.il
 * updates: centos.interhost.net.il

Listing all changelogs

==================== Installed Packages ====================
httpd-2.4.6-97.el7.centos.5.x86_64       installed
* Thu Mar 24 14:00:00 2022 CentOS Sources <bugs@centos.org> - 2.4.6-97.el7.centos.5
- Remove index.html, add centos-noindex.tar.gz
- change vstring
- change symlink for poweredby.png
- update welcome.conf with proper aliases

* Tue Mar 22 14:00:00 2022 Lubo? Uhliarik <luhliari@redhat.com> - 2.4.6-97.5
- Resolves: #2065243 - CVE-2022-22720 httpd: HTTP request smuggling
  vulnerability in Apache HTTP Server 2.4.52 and earlier
```

I got a report that the site has security vulnerabilities, which where supposed to be fixed in previous versions of Apache, so I am don't understand why I have this vulnerability if I have the latest version.

Can someone explain why it is like this?

Comment: Distributions, even rolling-release ones, always lag behind upstream releases.

Comment: apache 2.4.6 was released in in 2014, so it is a big lag. But I suspect version numbers on centos follow different numbering. I think that 2.4.6-97 is from 2022, but I am not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CentOS 7 was released in 2014, and included Apache 2.4.6 that was recent at the time the OS was released.

It is common practice for "stable" distributions to freeze the versions of the programs and not update them during the lifecycle of the OS, only backporting security patches if the version included in the OS is affected - which seems to be the case here, as from the output you provided it seems that there is some patch included that fixes a vulnerability found in version 2.4.52.

So no new features in Apache that were introduced after version 2.4.6 are included, but security patches are recent. This assures nothing will change during the update of the system in a way that makes Apache work differently from previous versions and - as a consequence - eg. your web applications to stop working properly.

The same practice applies for example for stable (LTS) Ubuntu versions, and many other distros.

As for the report about security vulnerabilities on your site, you should get more information about how the report was generated. Maybe it was generated by some "stupid" scanning tool that just looks at the software version advertised by the server (that is, 2.4.6), and based solely on this version number says that the site is vulnerable, without actually checking if the vulnerability is present or not.